# jQuery AJAX inside another AJAX call. Sync and finished issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I get a list of users with an AJAX call, but within the AJAX I call another AJAX to get some information that I could not get with the first AJAX call.

This is basically the structure I'm using, I've removed some unneccesary code that would just clutter, it is possible that there is some syntax errors here and there. 
But the code basically works but there are some issues.

```
function doAJAX(){
    $(".loading").show();
    $("#table").hide();

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
    data: { variable: varVariable},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("Action", "Controller")",
                data: { variable: value.id},
                success: function (data2) {
                $.each(data2, function (index2, value2) {
                    $("#tableBody").append("<tr><td>" + value.test +"</td><td>" + value2.test +"</td></tr>");
                });
                }
            });
       });
    }
    });
}
```

1. I hide my table at the start, when the AJAX is complete I want to show it again. Where exactly should I place it? Even if I place it at the end of the first AJAX success function it does not work because it gets executed while the other AJAX is still running.
2. For some reason my list ends up in an odd order everytime the AJAX runs, my list is sorted by alphabetical order yet with this AJAX it ends up random everytime, sometimes the user Adam is at the start, sometimes in the middle and so on. The list itself is fine and in correct order
3. I do a lot of mathematics that is probably slowing down the second AJAX call which is probably why it ends up in a weird order

Both of these issues are happening because the two AJAXs aren't running "together" but individually, is there a way to make them sync with each other and is there a good way to be sure that the AJAX is completed and now I can show my table?

Comment: You could add `async:false`to your second `ajax` call, but this may freeze the browser.

Comment: @HenrikP: the level of ajax call u are making here is very complicated. if possible try making a single ajax call to retrieve maximum data.

Comment: @ojovirtual This seems to do it. Also seems to work on slower computers unless the freeze issue is browser specific

Answer (score 0):

Sending ajax request inside a loop doesn't seem like a good idea. Why won't you send one ajax request with array of id's as a data, inside your serverside script just get "WHERE `id` IN (id_list)" array of user records and return them as json-encoded object, and then output it inside a double loop, first for `<tr>`, second for a list of fields.

I'm sorry i can't provide code, as i don't know what is being returned from your requests to server.